# Game of Life Hashlife Torus

Tags: algorithm, caching, conways-game-of-life

Is there a way of implementing the hashlife algorithm (to use caching) but with a universe bounded by hight and width that wraps around to the other sized?

Comment: Golly's hashlife algorithm supports torus world. I'm not sure how it is done.
In fact, when the world is a square whose side length is a power of 2, you can simply change the "expand universe" step from padding zeros to copying the whole pattern. But it would be much more complicated for other world size.